# Ionic 4 : Execution failed for task ':app:processDebugGoogleServices'. > No matching client found for package name 'com.ionic.personalhealthassistant'

Tags: firebase, cordova, ionic-framework, ionic4, ionic-native

Whenever I try to make android build I always get this error:

Execution failed for task ':app:processDebugGoogleServices'.

> No matching client found for package name 'com.ionic.personalhealthassistant'

I have placed my google-services.json file in **platforms->android** and **platforms->android->app** but whenever I try to my android build it automatically my google-services.json configuration to any other configuration thus my package_name also get changed. Package name change from **com.ionic.personalhealthassistant** to **com.github.cordova_plugin_firebase**

I have to remove the android platform and cordova-plugin-firebase and reinstall them but same error is occurring.

Autogenerating google-services.json

```
  "client_info": {
    "mobilesdk_app_id": "1:123:android:123",
    "android_client_info": {
      "package_name": "com.github.cordova_plugin_firebase"
    }
  },
```

My original google-services.json

```
  "client_info": {
    "mobilesdk_app_id": "1:794988011253:android:171bd43c7914d93d",
    "android_client_info": {
      "package_name": "com.ionic.personalhealthassistant"
    }
  },
```

Comment: https://github.com/arnesson/cordova-plugin-firebase/issues/1093#issuecomment-521959023 works for me